# Passing function variable as id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach "p-rating" to dynamic id to `$("<div id='slider'></div>")` 
**Expected result would be `$("<div id='slider p-rating'></div>")`**
I wanted to get the value strictly from **select** parameter as I'm planning to that be dyanamic. SELECT holds that value: p-rating but how to pass that value? I wanted space between ids

```
function initiateSlider (select) {
        var slider = $("<div id='slider'></div>").insertAfter( select ).slider({
        ...
        })
    }
$(function() {
        var select = $("#p-rating"); //plan-preference slider
        initiateSlider(select);    
      });
```

Comment: You should not do that, see `--->` http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10

Comment: Why do you want an id with spaces between words? Wouldn't it be interpreted as 2 separate ids, which isn't valid markup ?

Comment: Eventthough your intention is to add 2 ids for the same element, it will be considered as one id and id cannot contain spaces. This is invalid..

Comment: @jakker -- I have multiple slider. only way to distinguish is by adding an extra dynamic id. I want space between ids

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good time to use jQuery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/). So adding the p-rating to the div would go:

```
$('#slider').data('p-rating', select.val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you call the JQuery attr function while referencing it's ID attr within itself?

```
var sliderOriginalId = $("#slider").attr('id');

var sliderNewId = $("#slider").attr('id', sliderOriginalId + " *p-rating*");
```

EDIT:  This ID would be invalid with the space.

The thing is a single element (HTML tag) can't have more than one ID.  It can have more than 1 class though.  You might want to consider adding classes instead of id.  (Depending on what you are doing)

```
var slider = $("#slider").addClass("p-rating").addClass('slider');
```